# How to configure Firebase to support Android flavors?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use Firebase push notifications, but I am running into a configuration conflict. I would like to support different packages. With Google Maps, for example, I can add multiple packages under one app. This is because of Flavors. If My app package is `com.example`, I may have multiple Flavors such as `com.example.a`, `com.example.b`. I want to add support for push notifications for all of these Flavors.

How do I add multiple package names on the Firebase console?

[image]

Comment: Just create seperate google-services.json files for each package you have and put them in their respective src folders.

Comment: I see. Add this as an answer please. I will accept. Thank you

Comment: Comprehensive information about your options for organizing your Firebase Android builds can be found here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create seperate google-services.json files for each package you have and put them in their respective src folders

Comment: do I need to create a new project in the firebase console?

Comment: @RaviVaniya If you're setting flavors for handling different environments like prod, staging and dev, then it is recommended to setup multiple firebase projects.

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to  create a seperate google-services.json file for each Flavour,
just add the app to the Firebase Project and redownload the generated google-services.json file.

when you add an app the to the firebase Project, it automatically update the google-services.json file with the Client info you have added, so all you need is to download and replace your old one.